# how to limit the number of entries that print in the array

Tags: php, printing, listings, limiting

I am working in Drupal 7 on a custom Module using Php.

Under the "Cloud Providers:" section, I am trying to limit the number of entries that print out to only 4. The IF statment with a BREAK is my attempt to solve this issue so far.

I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours and its driving me nuts.  Any help would be appreciated.  I have put the code at the bottom of this.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

```
    <?php
/**
 * @file
 */
?>

    <div class="item-body">
      <div class="overview">

        <div class="label">Cloud Providers:</div>
        <div class="data">
          <?php 
            $i = 0;
            foreach($company['service_providers'] as $provider): ?>
            <div>
                <?php 
                if($i = 3) break;
                print $provider;
                $i++;
                ?>
            </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <?php print theme('cloud_computing_item_details', array('company' => $company)); ?> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; height: 5px;">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `==` instead of `=` to check equality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$providers = array_slice($company['service_providers'], 0, 4);
foreach($providers as $provider):
```

**EDIT**

or simply

```
foreach(array_slice($company['service_providers'], 0, 4) as $provider):
```

Comment: I tried it both ways and it still isnt working.  I make the changes and save teh file to the server but it still isnt effecting the website, good or bad.  i tried something like this in first

Comment: As always, clarify exactly what you mean by `isn't working`. Do var_dumps() of $company['service_providers'] and $providers to show exactly what is in each array. It's difficult to help you if we don't know the whole story

Comment: I take back what I said before. Everything is working correctly, it just takes a long time for the server to show the changes on the pages.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: would you guys vote on my post, im trying to boost my reputation. I am still new here.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`if($i = 3) break;`

should be:

`if($i == 3) break;`

whereas the way you have it currently, you are always setting `$i` equal to `3`

Comment: thank for the correction.  i completely forgot the difference.  unfortunately it still didnt fix the problem.  any other thoughts?